# Difference between baseUrl and callbackUrl

Tags: rest, api

I need to understand the basic difference between the baseURL and callbackURL.
Beside this, I need to know the meaning of this statement:
"**URL http://aggerator/order/tracker/url is a sample URL.
Callback url need to be shared by aggregator on which we can post order status.
Request sample:
POST request to http://aggerator/order/tracker/url?orderTransactionId=c06f7a38-57c0-479c-8a43-357ebf7a9f82**
"
The above mentioned is specified in API contract.What should be my api for this?

Answer (score 0):

A `baseURL` is an API's base URL. Let's say for X service: `https://api.xservice.com/v1`. It's something that gives the API provider.

In the documentation they say an endpoint for creating an user is `POST user`, then your API client should try to call `https://api.xservice.com/v1/user`.

Now, a `callbackURL` is something that you give as an API consumer, that way the service can notify you something is done. So let's say you tried to create an user with the previous example and they tell you they will notify you on a callback URL when it's done.

In the example they give, they tell you to pass an URL for one of the servers you control so they will tell you when a contract is completed and it should receive `orderTransactionId` as a parameter. That's a GET request. That ID is very likely (taken from context) the contract ID they sent you when you created the contract.

Comment: As far as I understand from your answer , the base URL from this example should be ** http://aggerator/order/tracker** and callbackURL should be (url) which the consumer will provide.

Comment: Hi Panjak, no. That's the path. The base URL is what goes before that path and is shared among paths.

Yes, the callback URL should be provided by the consumer and should be something that can manage.

BTW, if aggerator is the domain, then it needs to make it clearer. You can see the example I provided where there's a difference between the full URL and the path.